# Center figures in Bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am having trouble centering these figures. `.col-centered` is working on every other section that I have except for this one.

```
<section id="leadership" class="row col-md-7 company-leadership full-page col-centered">
     <h2 class="about-title text-center">Leadership</h2>
     <figure class="cap-bot col-md-2 team">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive">
          <figcaption>
               <h3>Jon Doe</h3>
               <em>Title</em>
          </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure class="cap-bot col-md-2 team">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive">
          <figcaption>
                <h3>Jon Doe</h3>
                <em>Title</em>
          </figcaption>
     </figure>

     <figure class="cap-bot col-md-2 team">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" class="img-responsive">
          <figcaption>
              <h3>Jon Doe</h3>
              <em>Title</em>
          </figcaption>
     </figure>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.col-centered{
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fa6RU/

BTW - you might not be able to see the 3 figures inline because of your resolution so zoom out until you see the 3 figures under leadership. I want them inline but centered right under leadership.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The images and figcaption elements are not being centered, its probably easiest to create a selector for them and specify a centering attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/fa6RU/2/

```
figure img { margin:0 auto; }
figcaption { text-align:center; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm trying to center the actual figures under leadership. I didn't want the text centered under the image.

Answer (score 0):

Okay if that's the case, just remove

```
figcaption { text-align:center; }
```

from Lowkase's answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pMm2/1/

Comment: That still doesn't center the actual figures. The images with descriptions should be centered under leadership.

Comment: Nope doesn't work. Sorry. Zoom out from the jsfiddle for you to see all three boxes under leadership and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: anybody else wanna give this a shot?